# How to define a type that applies a generic type to a union and results in a mapped union?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define a type in TypeScript that takes a generic type G and a union U as parameters. The goal is to apply the generic type to each element of the union and generate a new union where each element is the generic type parameterized by the corresponding element of the original union.

Here's an example to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
    type Union = A | B | C;
    type Dic<T> = Record<string, T>;
    type Distribute<G, U> = /* ??? */;
    type DistributedUnion = Distribute<Dic, Union>;
```

In this example, I want DistributedComponentData to be `Record<string, A> | Record<string, B> | Record<string, C>`. I've tried using a mapped type, but I haven't been able to get it working properly.

I'd appreciate any help or guidance on how to define the Spread type correctly to achieve the desired result. Thank you!

Comment: This is not possible directly because TypeScript lacks *higher kinded types* as requested in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  So `Distribute<Dic, Union>` will fail no matter how you define `Distribute`, because `Dic` isn't a type in TypeScript.  You need to write `Dic<XXX>` for some `XXX`.  There are ways to encode/emulate higher kinded types but they will all involve some alternative definition of `Dic`.  Does that fully address your question or am I missing something?